# Why cant I have a button below a listView?

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a page with a textView, a listView and then a button. The textView shows up along with the listView but the button will not display:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerTitleTaste"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/tastelist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
        >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addTasteTageButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Taste Tag" />



</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried moving the button above the listView and it showed up but then the listView didnt show up.

I would love to have it as TextView, then the listView with the button on the bottom. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for the `ListView`.

Comment: awesome that worked! What was going on there, I dont really understand? (I have to wait a few minutes before I am aloud to accept your answer.)

Comment: When using `fill_parent` or `match_parent` for height for example, the `View` will expand to take the full parent's height, which leaves no space for the button to fit on the screen.

Comment: Please read this blog post by Gabriele Mariotti about why this isn't a good idea: http://gmariotti.blogspot.de/2013/06/tips-for-listview-view-recycling-use.html?view=classic - It's very badfor performance: See the section "One last tip"

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/addTasteTageButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" in
android:text="Add Taste Tag" />
```